# I18Next TFunction translation not working in EJS template render

Tags: ejs, i18next

I have method that renders EJS templates and pass in the i18next.t function for the EJS template to do translations by setting the i18next t function as an attribute on the data object:

```
const data = {
                email: user.email,
                id: user.id,
                t: i18nT
            };
```

The data object is passed into ejs.renderFile(). The only way I can get the translation in the EJS template to work is when I set the i18nT variable to the t function from the i18next.init() functions call back. Otherwise it comes out blank. I see from the console output that the t function of the i18next instance, i18nInstance, is different to the t function set by the callback when initializing i18next.

```
function t() {
    var _this$translator;

    return this.translator && (_this$translator = 
       this.translator).translate.apply(_this$translator, arguments);
}
```

versus:

```
function () {
    return _this4.t.apply(_this4, arguments);
}
```

Why is the t function of the i18nInstance object obtained from calling i18next.createInstance() different than the one from the callback? The one from the instance object doesn not work in the EJS template render.

The full code sample:

```
let i18nInstance: i18n;
let i18nT;

const i18nextInitOptions = {
    backend: {
        loadPath: path.join(__dirname, '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'),
        addPath: path.join(__dirname, '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json')
    },
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'da',
    preload: ['da', 'en', 'nl'],
    returnEmptyString: false,
    returnNull: false,
    saveMissing: true
};
i18nInstance = await i18next
    .createInstance();
await i18nInstance
    .use(i18nextBackend)
    .init(i18nextInitOptions, async function (error, t) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        i18nT = t;
    });


console.log("i18nT: " + i18nT)
/*
The console.log outputs below show that i18nT when set from the callback is different to the 
i18nInstance.t.
i18nT: function () {
  return _this4.t.apply(_this4, arguments);
}
 */

console.log("i18nInstance.t: " + i18nInstance.t)
/*
console output:
i18nInstance.t: function t() {
      var _this$translator;

      return this.translator && (_this$translator = 
         this.translator).translate.apply(_this$translator, arguments);
}
*/

const data1 = {
            email: user.email,
            id: user.id,
            t: i18nT
        };

// Calling htmlFromTemplate with data1 with t = i18nT the translation in the EJS template works.
html = await this.htmlFromTemplate('ejsTemplateName.ejs', data1);

const data2 = {
            email: user.email,
            id: user.id,
            t: i18nextInstance.t
        };

// Calling htmlFromTemplate with data2 with t = i18nextInstance.t the translation in the EJS is empty.
html = await this.htmlFromTemplate('ejsTemplateName.ejs', data2);

private htmlFromTemplate(templateName: string, data: Object): Promise<String> {
        if (!templateName) return;
        const htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, '../assets/mail-templates/' + templateName);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ejs.renderFile(htmlPath, data,(renderErr, str) => {
                if (renderErr) {
                    appLogger.error('MAIL_RENDER: ' + renderErr, { templateName, data });
                    reject(renderErr);
                } else resolve(str);
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you pass the t function like this:

```
    const data2 = {
        email: user.email,
        id: user.id,
        t: i18nextInstance.t
    };
```

the t function is not bound to its original "this" anymore...

pass it this way:

```
    const data2 = {
        email: user.email,
        id: user.id,
        t: i18nextInstance.t.bind(i18nextInstance)
    };
```

more information here: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1528#issuecomment-748263313